# NixOS unable to find binaries/commands/packages installed (globally or locally) by asdf

Tags: nixos, home-manager

I recently started to use `NixOS 23.05`. I'm also using `Home Manager` (same version). Problem I'm facing is with [`asdf`](https://asdf-vm.com/). I installed it using `Home Manager`, and everything went fine. I then installed a couple of plugins, but any time I make them available globally, the system is unable to find the corresponding application/installation.

I think this may be an issue with `NixOS`, and the way it *register* the binaries/commands, but I'm not sure how to fix it, because everything was managed by `Home Manager`.

Anyone using this setup?

Comment: I'm not familiar with asdf but it's important *how* you installed these plugins. Also, you have to find out how asdf discovers plugins. NixOS does not "register" commands anywhere, it only puts files into certain directories.

Comment: `asdf` was installed using `Home Manager`. From that point, everything else is done using `asdf` — plugin and application/binary installations. `asdf` _registers_ (there are some shell scripts specific to `asdf` that should be run, similar to what `direnv` does when you `cd` into directories, but system-wide) itself with the system, so I guess that's what's missing here.

Comment: How does it "register" itself?

Comment: It's all part of the [initial installation](https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf) process. In the end, those shell scripts must be sourced every time a new shell is spawn. My guess is that something around those lines is not working correctly, and it's unable to recognize the newly installed binaries. Doing `reshim` doesn't work either.

Comment: What script are you sourcing to test this? (the path) What is `reshim`?

Comment: I placed a link in the previous comment for the scripts. It's part of the `asdf` installation, that's why I don't fully understand why `asdf` doesn't work entirely. I'm not sourcing them manually — they are nowhere to be found, probably because `Nix` manages the `asdf` installation. `reshim` is just a command from `asdf` to recreate _shims_ for a given version of an installed package — I rarely used that sometimes in the past (under `Arch Linux`) because some package was not available after install, and that sort of things.